# 'float object not callable in python

Tags: python, typeerror

I've read some of the questions about this error in Python, but I can't find the mistake in my code.

```
def integrand3(x,v):
    return (v[0]+v[1]*x+v[2]*x**2+v[3]*x**3+v[4]*x**4)*np.exp(x)*np.sin(np.pi()*x)

def ProdInt1proy(v,inf=0,sup=1):
    I,err = sp.quad(integrand3,inf,sup, args=v)
    return I

def Proyf(M,ProdInt):
    return sum((ProdInt(M[i])*M[i]) for i in range(len(M)))

Proyf(M,ProdInt1proy)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Esgrid/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/Users/Esgrid/Documents/CIMAT/Maestría Matemáticas Aplicadas/Semestre 1/Álgebra Lineal 1/Tarea 8 Álgebra.py", line 71, in <module>
    print Proyf(M,ProdInt1proy)
  File "/Users/Esgrid/Documents/CIMAT/Maestría Matemáticas Aplicadas/Semestre 1/Álgebra Lineal 1/Tarea 8 Álgebra.py", line 66, in Proyf
    return sum((ProdInt(M[i])*M[i]) for i in range(len(M)))
  File "/Users/Esgrid/Documents/CIMAT/Maestría Matemáticas Aplicadas/Semestre 1/Álgebra Lineal 1/Tarea 8 Álgebra.py", line 66, in <genexpr>
    return sum((ProdInt(M[i])*M[i]) for i in range(len(M)))
  File "/Users/Esgrid/Documents/CIMAT/Maestría Matemáticas Aplicadas/Semestre 1/Álgebra Lineal 1/Tarea 8 Álgebra.py", line 53, in ProdInt1proy
    I,err = sp.quad(integrand3,inf,sup, args=v)
  File "/Users/Esgrid/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 281, in quad
    retval = _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points)
  File "/Users/Esgrid/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 345, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
  File "/Users/Esgrid/Documents/CIMAT/Maestría Matemáticas Aplicadas/Semestre 1/Álgebra Lineal 1/Tarea 8 Álgebra.py", line 44, in integrand3
    return (v[0]+v[1]*x+v[2]*x**2+v[3]*x**3+v[4]*x**4)*np.exp(x)*np.sin(np.pi()*x)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

It happens when ProdInt1Proy is called, then enters integrand3 and the error is raised. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `np.pi()` should be `np.pi`

Comment: Rule number one: Show the exact error message, including traceback.

Comment: Rule number two: When you have a giant expression with an error somewhere within it but you have no idea where, break it up into separate expressions, one per line, and see which one is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"'float' object not callable" means your code appears to be making a function call on an object that's a simple floating point number rather than a function.

`np.pi` is a floating point constant, not a function; take the parentheses off it in `integrand3()`.